# Eclipse is not loading plugins placed into the "plugins" folder

Tags: maven, plugins, pom.xml, eclipse-neon

I'm currently in a desperate situation right now, I already tried dropping the JAR file into both the "plugins" folder I created inside the "dropins" directory and also into the other "plugins" folder that was already created. I add the "-clean" option into the target of the eclipse shortcut and then I start eclipse. I go to the "plug-ins" section and try searching my plugin, but it does not appear.

I am using Eclipse Jee Neon and this is the JAR plugin I am attempting to use. Can anyone help me resolve this?

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.5.0